# Extend the expiration date of a GPG key non-interactively

Tags: gnupg, public-key-encryption

I need to extend the expiration date of a GPG key, but all the answers or articles I can find do it interactively, for [example](https://superuser.com/questions/813421/can-you-extend-the-expiration-date-of-an-already-expired-gpg-key). I need to embed the logic in a shell script, so wondering how can I do it non-interactively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have your key `test@test.com` and your passphrase for that key is stored in file `passphrase.txt`, following command will non-interactively change expiration date:

```
printf "expire\n10w\nsave\n" | gpg --batch --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase-fd 3 --command-fd 0 --status-fd=2 --edit-key test@test.com 3<passphrase.txt
```

(If it doesn't work because of pinentry invocation see NOTE below.)

Brief explanation of command:

- `printf "expire\n10w\nsave\n"` sends these commands to gpg. `expire` changes expiry date of key, `10w` is 10 weeks, `save` is obvious.
- `--batch` says there will be no user input
- `--pinentry-mode loopback` allows piping passphrase file to gpg (see bellow)
- `--passphrase-fd 3` says that file descriptor `3` is where gpg should look for passphrase (note `3<passphrase.txt` at the end of command.
- `--command-fd 0` says that file descriptor `0` (or STDIN) is where gpg should source `--batch` commands from (`printf` portion in beginning of command).
- `--status-fd 2` says that status goes to `2` (or STDOUT), you might want to direct this to log.
- `--edit-key test@test.com` is key we want to edit

This answer should give you a good idea how to "automate" things with gpg. To make this complete you probably want to change expiration of encryption subkey, etc.

NOTE: Current versions of GnuPG don't allow to pipe passphrase easily (they default to gpg-agent and program called `pinentry`). For sake of simplicity I enabled piping passphrase by adding `allow-loopback-pinentry` to my `gpg-agent.conf`. Please note this is not secure and you likely want to implement your own `pinentry` (or use existing that suits your non-interactive workflow) and then set it in `gpg-agent.conf`

Comment: With gpg (GnuPG) 2.3.4 I get the feedback "gpg: can't do this in batch mode"