# How can I extend the expiration date of an expired GPG key?

Tags: gnupg

I am trying to extend the expiration date of an expired GPG/PGP key, mainly using the results from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/813421/can-you-extend-the-expiration-date-of-an-already-expired-gpg-key). My steps look like this :

```
$ gpg --list-keys
pub   rsa4096 2021-01-01 [C] [expired: 2023-01-01]
      <KEY>
uid           [ expired] myname myemail

$ gpg --edit-key <KEY>
gpg> expire
... (steping through)
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
gpg: make_keysig_packet: No secret key
```

I think the issue comes from the fact that I am trying to change the public key's expiration date by using that same (expired) key. It seems to me that I have no way to actually change the expiration date of my key.

Do you know how I can actually unexpire my key?

Comment: The output indicates that gpg cannot find the associated secret key for the keypair: `gpg: signing failed: No secret key`. Without the secret key, the expiration cannot be updated.